# how to rotate a object set in nslayout constraints

Tags: swift, rotation, transform, nslayoutconstraint

My swift code below is rotate a object at a 45 degree angle. My code below is having no effect on the rotation. I know I could rotate it i just create a frame but I need the constraints. I am not sure if this is possible but I would image it could be. All my code is below no storyboard needed. I tried to rate it on the box.transform line.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        box.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(box)
        box.backgroundColor = .red
        box.transform = box.transform.rotated(by: .pi)   
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        
        
            box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
            box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            box.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            box.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        
        ])
        
        
        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here rotating `box` by `pi` gives the same output because it's getting rotated 180 degrees. And `box` looks the same upside-down. If you're trying to rotate `box` by 45 degrees, then

Replace this:

```
box.transform = box.transform.rotated(by: .pi)
```

With this:

```
box.transform = box.transform.rotated(by: .pi/4)
```